# How to open ipynb files in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Once in a time, I can open the ipynb file within vscode. I can run cells and get result. For that siquation, I have an option when click right bar on the ipynb file showing "open with jupyter server". And now the option is gone, and I can only get the raw context.
However, when click the right mouse bar, there is a option "import jupyter notebook". It gives me a Null file with "Untitled" name.
So my question is how to open the ipynb file within vscode and it has a outlook like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Wjz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension:

https://github.com/jithurjacob/vscode-nbpreviewer

To use it, first open your ipython file (.ipynb). Then a little button appears on top of the editor that says 'show preview'.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was gobbled up by the Python extension for VSCode.

Now when I open a `.ipynb` in VSCode, I get a prompt at the bottom right asking, "Do you want to import the Jupyter Notebook into Python code?"

Instructions here:  [vscode jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) say click Import.

Now I have a second untitled file in addition to the open `.ipynb` file that has `#%% [Markdown]` for Markdown cells and `#%%` for code cells with `Run Cell|Run Above|Run Below" not necessarily in that order and not on every cell that I can click.

I click one of those and the Python Interactive window opens with the output.

[vscode jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHAzu.png)